# SSMTP configuration in Ubuntu 18.04 with Bash in my own system (one user)

Tags: bash, linux, email, configuration

This is how I configure the utility SSMTP that allows me to send mail via `smtp` protocol through a Google-Gmail proxy instead I'll have to manually configure an "heavier" Postfix bi-directional email server on my environment. I configure it in my own server environment that only I uses.

```
#!/bin/bash

myHostName="$HOSTNAME"
read -sp "Please paste your Gmail proxy email address (due to pasting, no verfication needed): " gmail_proxy_email_address  && echo
read -sp "Please paste your Gmail proxy email password (due to pasting, no verfication needed):" gmail_proxy_email_password && echo

cat <<-EOF > /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf
    root=${gmail_proxy_email_address}
    AuthUser=${gmail_proxy_email_address}
    AuthPass=${gmail_proxy_email_password}
    hostname=${myHostName}
    mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587
    rewriteDomain=gmail.com
    FromLineOverride=YES
    UseTLS=YES
    UseSTARTTLS=YES
EOF
```

Would you do this even otherwise? Something to shorten? Some alternative utility maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I recommend `set -eu` early in the script to abort on errors and to make any use of unset variables be an error.

Second, If `HOSTNAME` is unset, we probably want to fallback to running the `hostname` command.  There seems little point in assigning it to a variable we use only once:

```
# (simplified to show only the relevant part)
cat <<EOF
    hostname=${HOSTNAME:-$(hostname)}
EOF
```

Then we can delete the line `myHostName="$HOSTNAME"`, as it's no longer used.

Third, the other thing missing is `umask 077` to ensure that the file isn't created readable by anyone else (important, as it contains cleartext credentials).

---

When reading email address, it shouldn't be necessary to hide it using `read -s` - only the password ought to be a secret.

When reading the password, there's no need to mention that confirmation is not required, as we wouldn't normally expect it here: we use confirmation when *creating* a password (so the user doesn't accidentally lock herself out of her account by a simple invisible typing error).  Here, we're entering an *existing* password, and any error can be corrected just by re-running the script.

---

## Edited script

Applying my suggestions, we get:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -eu

umask 077  # Ensure others can't read the file

read -p "Please paste your Gmail proxy email address: " \
     gmail_proxy_email_address
read -sp "Please paste your Gmail proxy email password:" \
     gmail_proxy_email_password && echo

cat <<-EOF > /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf
    root=${gmail_proxy_email_address}
    AuthUser=${gmail_proxy_email_address}
    AuthPass=${gmail_proxy_email_password}
    hostname=${HOSTNAME:-$(hostname)}
    mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587
    rewriteDomain=gmail.com
    FromLineOverride=YES
    UseTLS=YES
    UseSTARTTLS=YES
EOF
```